# TypeError: precision_score() got an unexpected keyword argument 'Y_pred'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook

Well, I have just this problem and if there is any specific terminology to ask about it, [I don't know that]. The question is a question. If somebody can guide me, please. I'm working with jupyter notebook on Ubuntu. and the code is also given below for the reference.

```
from sklearn import datasets

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

from sklearn import svm    # The Support Vector Machine

from sklearn import metrics

import pandas as pd
```

#-------------Libraries Block-End.

## Pull the breast cancer data directly from the web.

```
cancer_data = datasets.load_breast_cancer()

X = cancer_data.data
Y = cancer_data.target
```

## Prints the data

```
print(cancer_data['target'])
```

## Splits the data

```
X_train,X_test, Y_train,Y_test = train_test_split(cancer_data.data, cancer_data.target,test_size=0.2, random_state=209)
```

#Defining the Classifier Support Vector Machine (SVM)

```
clss = svm.SVC(kernel="linear")

#cls = svm.SVC(kernel="rbg"), C = 0.1, gamma = 0.1)
```

#Applying the fitting

```
clss.fit(X_train, Y_train)
```

## Predict

```
pred = clss.predict(X_test)
```

## Display all the results

```
print("accuracy:", metrics.accuracy_score(Y_test, Y_pred = pred))

print("precision:", metrics.precision_score(Y_test, Y_pred = pred))

print("recall:", metrics.precision_score(Y_test, Y_pred = pred))

print(metrics.classification_report(Y_test, Y_pred = pred))
```

Comment: Thank you for the helping hand Mr. @Saeid Amini, formatting just gone bad here in my post. I'm adding the screen shot and code again. if you may please check it again.

Comment: I tried to add the code in my comment but its too long for a comment. What shall i do now? THE ERROR IS STILL THERE.

Comment: you have a typo, it should be ```y_pred=``` , note the y is not capitalized

Comment: [Problem Solved]--Thanks a lot @StupidWolf,
I did not look it.... ... but if its a variable then why is that restriction to type only the small y ? ... and no other character is accepted.

Comment: it is an argument. see https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html